# Set Cross Domain Cookies with Iframe- issue

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, cookies

I want to set cross domain cookies. Cookies has been set successfully, if login page is not redirect to other page. If page redirected after login then cookies is not set. what is the issues?

I am using following code  to setcookies on

```
            echo "<iframe style='display:none;' id='myiframe' 
src='http://b.com/cookies.php?username=$username&password=$password&token=$token'>";
            echo "</iframe>";
```

if I use die(); function, then cookies is set on site b.com.

if i redirect this page to another page, cookies is not set.

/* Redirect to login page */

```
header("Location: $loginPage");
    exit();
```

why?
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps you, but I created an NPM module for setting cookies across domains.  If you wanted to use JS to set/get the cross-domain cookie, this may work better.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-toss